# How and when did 'being fired' come to mean losing one's job?

Tags: etymology, american-english

I searched this site and also searched etymology online and could find nothing about this question.

The [Ngram AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fired+from+job&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfired%20from%20job%3B%2Cc0) shows that the phrase 'fired from job' began in the early 1920s for AmE and the [Ngram BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fired+from+job&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfired%20from%20job%3B%2Cc0) indicates that BrE only begins to have results from the late 1960s.

In BrE, the phrase 'being sacked' ([Ngram BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+sacked&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeing%20sacked%3B%2Cc0)) is more popular and is more understandable as one would carry a sack home with any personal possessions, much as today people are seen with the ubiquitous cardboard box.

Where does the expression come from and why did it suddenly appear in the 1920s in the USA ?

Note: The Ngrams probably do not mean a lot, as there must be overlap with other meanings of 'being sacked' and merely querying 'being fired' would be useless.

---

Edit After Comment : The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=given+the+sack&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiven%20the%20sack%3B%2Cc0) for 'given the sack' in BrE. Some correlation with 'being fired' in AmE.

Further Edit : The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/70513?rskey=kXX9Al&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) does not (that I can find) refer to losing a job but there is a considerable entry for 'fire' with regard to the discharge of a weapon so I am beginning to see that 'fire' from a job means to 'discharge' someone and the analogy is to weaponry.

Comment: The same metaphorical development of the verb _fire_ (first: lighting fire; then: using fire to ward off or repel; then: shooting off a projectile with fire; then: ‘shooting off’ a person from their job) is also found in the Nordic languages, where it’s definitely attested well before the 1920s, though I don’t know how long before. (Also, is _sacked_ really more understandable? The explanation you give never occurred to me before – I’d always sort of half-imagined someone being stuffed into a sack, which somehow meant losing their job…)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, AFAIK, Brits also use *sacked* in the form "given the sack" which would make a much clearer connection to the origin OP attributed to it.

Comment: I thought 'being sacked' involved being put into a sack and left on the side of the road.

Comment: As a BrE native, I can confirm the existence of "given the sack".  I could easily be persuaded it is the older form too.

Comment: As another BrE native, I was taught as a child that being "sacked" or "given the sack" meant you were "made redundant", i.e. implies no fault of your own, just that your job role didn't exist any more; whereas "being fired" meant you did something wrong and were dismissed as a direct result.

Comment: @Vicky Redundancy, in my understanding is not 'being sacked'. 'Being sacked' is a matter of fault or incompetence, I would say. I don't think there is a distinction between 'fired' and 'sacked'. (Isn't redundancy a UK process, not a USA one ?)

Comment: When I  was young someone explained that in earlier eras workmen took their tools to work in a sack. When "fired", they were "given the sack" into which to put their tools, then leave.

Comment: @NigelJ: In US English, the distinction mentioned by Vicky is between being "fired" and being "laid off", although we would understand "made redundant" to mean the latter.

Comment: @Mawg Why would you need to give someone a sack, then, if they've been taking their tools to work in a sack for the last *n* days of work?

Comment: @AzorAhai In the old days, one wasn't provided with tools at work. One provided 'the tools of one's trade' oneself. And over time, would build up a collection at one's place of work. One would be handed a sack in which to remove one's own possessions from the premises, just as today, we use a cardboard box to empty one's desk.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say (+1). If you signed up to do some masonry at a cathedral, you expected your grandson to finish your work. You may well have taken your tools in a satchel or sack on the first day, but even a sack was too valuable to leave at work for a few years, to you took it home & used it. And, if dismissed, you were (I imagine) given (or loaned?) the oldest, rattiest sack around & told to get out.

Comment: In fact, I know a few carpenters who work months on end at ay a shopping centre, or block of flats, who start off taking in a smallish toolbox and then take in specialist tools in drib s& drabs, then having to come into the local and ask who can loan them a large chest 9and a van) to get their tools off-site (in London, many of them never had any need to learn to drive). But, I digress ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**to fire** in the sense of being fired:  [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fire#etymonline_v_5966)

> The sense of "sack, dismiss from employment" is recorded by 1885 (with
>   out; 1887 alone) in American English. This probably is a play on the
>   two meanings of discharge (v.): "to dismiss from a position," and "to
>   fire a gun," influenced by the earlier general sense "throw (someone)
>   out" of some place (1871).

and from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/th/class/210794)

> - fire 1879
> - transitive orig. U.S. slang. To dismiss (a person) from a job or    position; to sack.

Comment: I think the key is "discharge" here.

Comment: In Danish we have "fyre"=fire, but the etymology here is from lower German "firen", meaning celebrate/take the time off. It would be strange if there isn't a similar connection in English

Comment: *Firen* would appear to be linked to the German *Ferien* "holiday" and the liturgical term *feria* (which is just "day").

Comment: There's no English word cognate to *firen* meaning to take time off, so I'd be surprised if there is a connection. Unless a bunch of Britons detected a shortfall in the wide variety of terms for losing one's job and decided they'd have to raid Plattdeutsch.

Answer (score 13):

There’s a slightly earlier sense of “fired” meaning “eject or dismiss” that just dates to 1877 according to the OED:

> She was advised to ‘hire a hall’, and the chairman was asked to ‘fire her out’.
>   <sub>[Annals of the Great Strikes in the United States](https://books.google.com/books?id=ilJ9AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA415&lpg=PA415&dq="She+was+advised+to+%E2%80%98hire+a+hall%E2%80%99,+and+the+chairman+was+asked+to+%E2%80%98fire+her+out%E2%80%99".)</sub>

The OED’s earliest citation in the no-more-job sense is from the  1879 Cincinnati Enquirer (reprinted [here](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=THWG18790925.1.2)):

> Professional Slang... Fired, Banged, Shot Out—When a performer is discharged he is one of the above.

The OED connects this to firing a gun: just like a bullet, whoever gets fired is outta there real fast.

Comment: I've never heard of "banged" to mean fired. Ironically, nowadays, if a boss "banged" an employee, it'd likely be *the boss* that gets fired instead of the employee. Language is weird.

Comment: So it seems likely that some time before 1879, the slang terms "fired", "banged", and "shot out" became popular among theatrical performers. For one reason or another, "fired" became universal, while "banged" and "shot out" both fell into disuse.

Answer (score 2):

This source, [Right Attitudes](http://www.rightattitudes.com/2010/02/03/folklore-origin-expression-you-are-fired/), admits that its explanation for ***being fired*** may be a legend.

> ...legend has it that the phrase originated in the 1910s at the
>   National Cash Register (NCR) Company.

The founder of NCR, John Henry Patterson, was "quirky".  The article states that he was "a food and fitness fanatic and had his employees weighed every six months."  This quirkiness makes the following explanation of the origin of **being fired** marginally more plausible.

The article cites two cases of Patterson dismissing an employee -- one of whom was Thomas  Watson Sr., who went on to found IBM -- **and then ordering his desk taken outside and set afire.**!  Thus, although it was the employee's desk that was fired, the phrase was used of the employee.

The article states its source as:

> Keynote address by Mark Hurd, then-president and COO of Teradata at
>   Kellogg School of Management’s Digital Frontier Conference on 17- and
>   18-Jan-2003. Teradata was previously a division of NCR Corporation,
>   the company Patterson founded.

Comment: Which would appear to be contradicted by the above references from the 1800s.

Comment: @HotLicks Is it not likely, if the NCR story is true, that Patterson was giving physical expression to the existing term "fired"? It also seems a bit extreme to destroy a piece of your own property just because you had dismissed the person who had been using it.

Comment: @BoldBen - Yep, this is likely the case.  Patterson's actions were a physical expression of the already-existing idiomatic meaning.  (But keep in mind that someone as wealthy as Patterson at that time wouldn't have batted an eyelash at destroying $10 of the company's property to flex his authority.)

Comment: @HotLicks One of the legends surrounding Henry Royce (the engineer who had Charlie Rolls as a business partner) was more extreme. In the days when apprenticed craftsmen were expected to buy and own all their own hand tools, if Royce found someone on the shop floor using an adjustable wrench, he disposed of it by throwing it through the factory window into a nearby river. The user was dismissed on the spot with no reference, *and the cost of mending the broken window was deducted from his final wage packet*. But he did make some pretty good cars...

Comment: @alephzero - What if he was using an adjustable spanner instead?

Comment: A crap reference is not a reference.

Comment: @Fattie - And a crap comment is just crap.

Comment: @alephzero [L Gardner & Sons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._Gardner_and_Sons) who built high quality marine and lorry diesel engines used to prohibit workers in their factories having hammers above a very small weight because they were working to sufficiently close tolerences that parts were supposed to fit together without the use of a hammer. I understood that having a larger hammer in your tool kit was enough to get you the sack.

Answer (score 0):

Fired ,, where someone has done something wrong and punishment was to go shovel coal in to the fires for boilers and also long distant trains , as this saying cant go on in the same way of punishment it's just changed Into  or used now as the same as someone getting terminated from a job .  And it was not trumps saying or moto its lord alan sugars saying as the apprentice is a uk t.v show first .

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Some corroboration for the boliler theory would be good here. Also, if you see the highest-placed answer here, the term predates even Lord Sugar.

Comment: In India if I say, "I was fired by my supervisor this morning", it just mans, "I was reprimanded..." Even the bosses use the word 'firing' to mean, "reprimanding".

Answer (score 0):

The origins of "to fire" = dismiss, release from employment ***seem*** to be nautical, as the verb seems to originate in a nautical context in the idea of releasing a rope (or similar):

OED

> † fire, v.2 Forms:  pre-17 fyre. transitive. To let out (an anchor cable); = **veer** v.1 3a.
>
> Origin: Either (i) a variant or alteration of another lexical item. Or (ii) a borrowing from Dutch.
>
> Etymology: Either a variant of veer (v.), or directly from its etymon, the Dutch *vieren* (pron. /fi:rən/), Obsolete. rare.

The OED for "veer" is

> **Veer** (v.)  transitive. To let out (an anchor cable); = veer v. 3a.
>   Nautical.
>
> 1. To allow (a sheet [i.e. a ship's rope] or other sail-line) to run out to some extent; *to let out by releasing.* frequently used figuratively.
>
> c1540   J. Bellenden tr. H. Boece Hyst. & Cron. Scotl. iv. xiv. f. 48v/2   Thay fyrit thair takillis, & sank down in ye middis of ye see. = They released their tackle (*ropes >anchor rope, etc*) and sank down in the middle of the ocean.

Comment: Hmm, in view of the OED the above seems unlikely: "III. To eject or dismiss, and related senses. -- 21.a. transitive. To forcibly eject or expel (a person) from a place; Probably [an] allusion to the speed [of] a bullet.
1920   J. Hay ‘No Clue!’ ix. 115   This Mildred Brace claimed she had suffered injury at your hands. You fired her out of your office.  22. transitive. To dismiss (a person) from a job or position; to sack. 1879   Cincinnati Enquirer 7 Sept. 10/7   Professional Slang... Fired, Banged, Shot Out—When a performer is discharged he is one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Linking the expression "fired" with having one's home burned is not far fetched. OED shows a similar relationship between the expression "getting the sack" and destruction of one's property. The entry is
"the sack [singular] (formal) the act of stealing or destroying property in a captured town. Example: The sack of Rome."

Answer (score -2):

The expression 'to get fired' comes from long ago Clans that wanted to get rid of unwanted people, so they would burn their houses instead of killing them, creating the term 'Got fired'.

Comment: This would benefit from having an authoritative source to support it.